Looking for an identity to simplify an infinite sum involving hypergeometric 2F1's
From a physics context I have landed into
$$\chi(h,N) = \sum_{q=0}^{\infty} \ (\frac{4h}{(1+h)^2})^{qN} \cdot \frac{ \Gamma(qN+\frac{1}{2})\Gamma(qN-\frac{1}{2})}{2 \pi\Gamma(2qN+1)}    \cdot   {}_2F_1[ qN+\frac{1}{2}, \ qN-\frac{1}{2}; \ 2qN+1; \frac{4h}{(1+h)^2}]$$
Where $N \in \mathbb{N}^{+}$ and $h \in \mathbb{R}$.
Previously I found regularized hypergeometric 3F2, which I managed to write as 2F1 times some combinatorial prefactors.Here N denotes system size, so for large N the leading contribution comes from $q=0$ as the gamma functions in the prefactor drops as $e^{-n \log n}$. But for small and intermediate $N$ certain interesting features emerge when observed empirically through blind numerics.
Therefore I want to obtain a better representation of this sum. I have searched most noted books and wolfram function repository, yet haven't found anything.
How to go about this?

May I ask about the context ?

Surely. It is coming from an exact approach to obtain energy per site of a finite transverse field ising model. More context can be found in https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kOxbOMO8EYapzOZfAuPGMGWxhbFeXnoK/view? usp=sharing. Any insight on other parts of the derivation would also be appreciated.

Would writing it as a sum over derivatives of Elliptic integral of the second kind help?

Dear user ssm, no it does not.
